# Find dimensional formula of $\alpha$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, dimensional-analysis

> The power delivered by a force is given by the relation $$P=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}e^{-\beta t},$$ where $t$ is time. Find the dimensional formula for $\alpha$.

So, $-\beta t$ doesn't make sense for the dimensional formula of $P$. But then we have two unknowns and one equation since we do not know if $\beta$'s dimensions. But then if I put $\beta t$ as dimensionless, it fits just right with the answer $([ML^2 T^{-4}])$ . But does this happen exactly. Why is  $\beta t$ dimensionless, because we are just using it's numerical value. Please help. I don't understand it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dimensional analysis - how to find the dimensions of a variable inside an angle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/284356/)

Answer (score 1):

$\beta t$ must be dimensionless because it is the argument of a function (read [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/272599/why-arent-trigonometric-functions-dimensionless-regardless-of-the-argument) thread). Therefore

$$
[\beta] = t^{-1}
$$

Comment: So is it like exponential functions have to be dimensionless?? Compulsory??

Comment: @Sri The argument must be dimensionless